# adding rows to pandas dataframe eventually leads to large performance reduction

Tags: python, pandas

I have been using this method to add new rows to a dataframe:

```
while m.next()
    df.loc[counter] = [m.value1, m.value2]
    counter += 1
    if counter > 100000:
        break
```

After 10000+ row additions the program start slowing down to eventually a crawl. Is there a way to do this without leading to performance issues?

Comment: Adding new rows to a DataFrame is always going to be slow.  DataFrames aren't really appropriate for that use case.  You should try to figure out how big you need it to be and create it with the final size to begin with.

Comment: show us your code includng the loop?

Comment: Appending to an array, list, series or df will be highly non-performant and should be advised, please show what you are trying to do as comparison operations can be vectorised, I'd advise perhaps creating a new df and merging.

Comment: Since the data is streamed out one row at a time from a third party program it cannot be vectorised. Possibly using PyTables might be a better but not sure if flush() will remove the data from memory to the hdisk. Will see if I can give a more thorough explanation of the problem.

Comment: There is a comment about exactly this in the grey box here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#concatenating-objects

Comment: I see your point, it is making a full copy each time which is very inefficient.